# Lucene.Net Indexing : Can I do partial match on field based on the query?

Tags: indexing, lucene.net, partial

Can I do partial match on the index fields based on the query supplied?
here is my problem:
I have a indexed documents on fields 
    ProviderName, State, Age,Specialty, Zip

```
 Doc1:Smith , GA, 40, SU, 30004
 Doc2:Smith , AL, 40, PC, 22031
 Doc3:Sanders, GA , 39, PC ,30350

My query is Name = Smith AND Specialty=PC and Zip=30350
```

As per the query there is no exact match. But can i do something where I can return return 
Doc3 since it has a partial match for Specialty and Zip match or return Doc2 since it has 1 match on field Speialty?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a query like this:

```
(Name=Smith AND Specialty=PC) OR (Name=Smith AND Zip=30350) OR (Specialty=PC AND Zip=30350).
```

Alternatively, you can make OR query and then get top ranked documents (since documents that match more terms get more rank):

```
Name=Smith OR Specialty=PC OR Zip=30350
```

Comment: Thanks Norfolc. I ended up doing the way you mentioned and am able to rank them by the score.

Comment: @AjaySalian, if my answer have helped you, please accept it